# Set Excel (Xml) column width

Tags: php, xml, excel

I'm programmatically creating an Excel file with PHP.

I'm struggling to set column width and row height, ss:Width="120" in the columns is just ignored!
The following code is taken from Microsoft [blog page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2006.01.blogtales.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
<ss:Workbook xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">\n
<ss:Styles>\n
    <ss:Style ss:ID="1">\n
        <ss:Font ss:Bold="1"/>\n
    </ss:Style>\n
</ss:Styles>\n
<ss:Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">\n
    <ss:Table>\n
        <ss:Column ss:Width="120"/>\n
        <ss:Column ss:Width="80"/>\n
        <ss:Column ss:Width="120"/>\n
        <ss:Row ss:StyleID="1">
            <ss:Cell ss:Height="25">\n
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">First Name</ss:Data>\n
            </ss:Cell>\n
            <ss:Cell>\n
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">Last Name</ss:Data>\n
            </ss:Cell>\n
            <ss:Cell>\n
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">Phone Number</ss:Data>\n
            </ss:Cell>\n
        </ss:Row>\n
        <ss:Row>\n
            <ss:Cell>\n
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">Nancy</ss:Data>\n
            </ss:Cell>\n
            <ss:Cell>\n
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">Davolio</ss:Data>\n
            </ss:Cell>\n
            <ss:Cell>\n
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String">(206)555-9857</ss:Data>\n
            </ss:Cell>\n
        </ss:Row>\n
    </ss:Table>\n
</ss:Worksheet>\n
</ss:Workbook>\n
```

And the headers are

```
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=" . $this->encoding);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.xls"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0,pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
```

I achieved everything I wanted style-wise, except width and less importantly, height

I'm using LibreOffice on Ubuntu to view the results

Comment: That does not look complete to me. Have you looked at this page: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2006.01.blogtales.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @jkpieterse yes, I followed these instructions. Even if I paste their example code and echo it, it does not set the column width as it is supposed to...

Comment: Can you upload one of your result files so we can test on a proper Office installation? LibreOffice isn't Excel by any means.

Comment: @jkpieterse I understand that, but the goal is to create a format readable in all major OS as well as google docs. Anyway, precisely because of the stated above, I abandoned the idea to create the file from scratch, going to use one of the libraries.

Comment: I was going to suggest that next :-)